# How to uncheck checked radio buttons in jquery?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

What I want to do is pretty simple. Look at this form:

```
<input type="radio" id="Car"><label for="Car">Car</label>
<input type="radio" id="Bike"><label for="Bike">Car</label>
```

With the following script:

```
$("input:radio").button().click(function(event){
    $(this).siblings().prop('checked', false);
});
```

Now this code doesn't make the radio buttons mutually exclusive. If  I change "radio" to "checkbox" everything works ok. But I want to understand why this doesn't work with radio input? Is this a bug with jQuery or I am missing something important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to group radios they need to share common `name`. The checked property is then managed by browser

HTML copied directly from [jQueryUI radio demo](http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio)

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio"><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked"><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio"><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
```

Comment: Thanks much. I wanted to write in my question that it's my understanding that radios should be mutually exclusive checkboxes by definition, but I just can't understand why that doesn't happen automatically and I need to script it. So that's what I was missing... hmm...

Comment: Oh, and about the jQueryUI radio demo, I had changed from "buttonset" to "button" because of styling, and I misunderstood that what made that code work was "buttonset"... not the COMMON NAME between the radios :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean, how to make them mutually exclusive? Assign them the same "name" attribute.